# SQL Query to find the last day of the month in 6 months time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to write a bit of SQL that will give the last day of the month in 6 months time.

E.g. if I have of a date of inspection 15-07-2015 I want the next inspection date to be 31-01-2016

The date of inspection could be any day of any month

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: You should update the question and tag it with the specific version of SQL Server that you are using as version 2012+ has a function to do this, while in older versions you have to do some arithmetic with dateadd/datediff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+ you can use the [eomonth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function to get the last day of a month:

```
declare @d date = '2015-07-15'
select eomonth(@d,6)
```

result: `2016-01-31`

The function takes a date and an optional integer that specifies the number of months to add to the date parameter.

Answer (score 5):

if i understand. that's it

```
declare @d date = '2015-07-15'
    SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@d)+7,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
declare @FindLastDay datetime
set @FindLastDay=CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(M,6,'2015-07-15'),120)
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @FindLastDay) + 1, 0)) as DATE)
```

output:

```
2016-01-31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DateAdd(D, Day(DateAdd(Month, 7, '2015-07-15')) * -1, DateAdd(M, 7, '2015-07-15'))
```

Yields the answer you expect.